# Round-off error in translated JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, fortran

I translated an old Fortran program that simulates a damped driven linear oscillator.  Here's the JS:

```
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true */
/*global VERLET */
/*global FORCE */
/*global $ */
function driven() {
  "use strict";
//MODULE shared
  //USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV,dp=>REAL64!modern DOUBLE PRECISION
  //INTEGER :: i
  //INTEGER, PARAMETER :: i_max=5000
  //REAL(dp) :: x_read,v_read,const0,gamma,A_o,dt
  //REAL(dp), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: x,v,a,E,dE,time
  //REAL(dp), PARAMETER :: m=1.0
  var i_max,
    i_max_read,
    i,
    x_read,
    v_read,
    const0,
    const0_read,
    gamma,
    gamma_read,
    A_o,
    A_o_read,
    dt,
    dt_read,
    x,
    x_plot,
    v,
    v_plot,
    a,
    a_plot,
    time,
    f_osc,
    sim,
    result,
    nonlinear;
  //i_max = 5000;
  x = [];
  x_plot = [];//new combined array for Flot plotting
  v = [];
  v_plot = [];//new combined array for Flot plotting
  a = [];
  a_plot = [];//new combined array for Flot plotting
  time = [];
  f_osc = [];//unlike Fortran, this needs to be an array
//END MODULE shared

//PROGRAM nonlinear
  nonlinear = document.forms.nonlinear;
  //USE shared
  //IMPLICIT NONE
  //EXTERNAL VERLET
  //ALLOCATE(x(i_max + 1))
  //ALLOCATE(v(i_max + 1))
  //ALLOCATE(a(i_max + 1))
  //ALLOCATE(E(i_max + 1))
  //ALLOCATE(dE(i_max + 1))
  //ALLOCATE(time(i_max + 1))
  //PRINT *, ' '
  //PRINT *, 'Initial position of the mass? [m]'
  //PRINT *, ' '
  //READ *, x_read
  x_read = nonlinear.elements.x_read;
  //x(1) = x_read
  x[0] = parseFloat(x_read.value);
  //PRINT *, ' '
  //PRINT *, 'Initial velocity of the mass? [m/sec]'
  //PRINT *, ' '
  //READ *, v_read
  v_read = nonlinear.elements.v_read;
  //v(1) = v_read
  v[0] = parseFloat(v_read.value);
  //PRINT *, ' '
  //PRINT *, 'Value of k/m? [1/sec^2]'
  //PRINT *, ' '
  //READ *, const0
  const0_read = nonlinear.elements.const0_read;
  const0 = parseFloat(const0_read.value);
  //PRINT *, ' '
  //PRINT *, 'Value of the damping coefficient? [kg/sec]'
  //PRINT *, ' '
  //READ *, gamma
  gamma_read = nonlinear.elements.gamma_read;
  gamma = parseFloat(gamma_read.value);
  //PRINT *, ' '
  //PRINT *, 'Amplitude of the external force? [N]'
  //PRINT *, ' '
  //READ *, A_o
  A_o_read = nonlinear.elements.A_o_read;
  A_o = parseFloat(A_o_read.value);
  i_max_read = nonlinear.elements.i_max_read;
  i_max = parseFloat(i_max_read.value);
  //PRINT *, ' '
  //PRINT *, 'Time-step of the system? [sec]'
  //PRINT *, ' '
  //READ *, dt
  //PRINT *, ' '
  dt_read = nonlinear.elements.dt_read;
  dt = parseFloat(dt_read.value);
  sim = i_max * dt;
  result = sim.toFixed(1);
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result;
  //time(1) = 0.0
  time[0] = 0.0;
  //i = 1
  i = 0;
  //DO
  do {
    //IF(i > i_max) EXIT
    //CALL VERLET
    VERLET(i, x, v, a, time, f_osc, dt, A_o, const0, gamma);
    x_plot[i] = [time[i], x[i]];
    v_plot[i] = [time[i], v[i]];
    a_plot[i] = [time[i], a[i]];
    //time(i + 1) = time(i) + dt
    time[i + 1] = time[i] + dt;
    //i = i + 1
    i = i + 1;
  //END DO
  } while (i < i_max);
  //OPEN(7, file='xt.dat', status='unknown')
  //WRITE(7,'(2f16.6)') (time(i),x(i),i=1,i_max)
  //CLOSE(7)
  //DEALLOCATE(x)
  //DEALLOCATE(v)
  //DEALLOCATE(a)
  //DEALLOCATE(E)
  //DEALLOCATE(dE)
  //DEALLOCATE(time)
  function doPlot(position) {//Flot
    $.plot("#placeholder", [//data
      {
        data: x_plot,
        label: "Position (m)",
        yaxis: 1,
        color: "red"
      },
      {
        data: v_plot,
        label: "Velocity (m/sec)",
        yaxis: 2,
        color: "green"
      },
      {
        data: a_plot,
        label: "Acceleration (m/sec/sec)",
        yaxis: 3,
        color: "blue"
      }
    ],//options
      {
        xaxis: { axisLabel: "Time (sec)" },
        yaxes: [
          { font: { color: "red" } },
          { font: { color: "green" } },
          { font: { color: "blue" } },
          { alignTicksWithAxis: position === "left" ? 1 : null }
        ],
        legend: {
          position: "nw",
          labelBoxBorderColor: null
        }
      }
      );
  }
  doPlot("left");
//END PROGRAM nonlinear
}

//SUBROUTINE VERLET()
function VERLET(i, x_temp, v_temp, a_temp, t_temp, f_osc_temp, dt, A_o, const0, gamma) {
  "use strict";
  //USE shared
  //IMPLICIT NONE
  //REAL(dp) :: x_temp,v_temp,t_temp,f_osc
  //EXTERNAL FORCE,ENERGY
  var m;
  m = 1.0;
  //x_temp = x(i)
  //v_temp = v(i)
  //t_temp = time(i)
  //CALL FORCE(x_temp,v_temp,t_temp,f_osc)
  FORCE(i, x_temp, v_temp, t_temp, f_osc_temp, A_o, const0, gamma);
  //x_temp = x(i)
  //v_temp = v(i)
  //CALL ENERGY!don't think I'm actually using this; no INTENT(OUT)
  //a(i) = f_osc/m
  a_temp[i] = f_osc_temp[i] / m;
  //x(i + 1) = x(i) + v(i)*dt + 0.5*a(i)*dt*dt
  x_temp[i + 1] = x_temp[i] + v_temp[i] * dt + 0.5 * a_temp[i] * dt * dt;
  //x_temp = x(i + 1)
  //v_temp = v(i)
  //t_temp = time(i + 1)
  //CALL FORCE(x_temp,v_temp,t_temp,f_osc)
  FORCE(i, x_temp, v_temp, t_temp, f_osc_temp, A_o, const0, gamma);
  //a(i + 1) = f_osc/m
  a_temp[i + 1] = f_osc_temp[i] / m;
  //v(i + 1) = v(i) + 0.5*(a(i + 1) + a(i))*dt
  v_temp[i + 1] = v_temp[i] + 0.5 * (a_temp[i + 1] + a_temp[i]) * dt;
  //x_temp = x(i + 1)
  //v_temp = v(i + 1)
  //CALL ENERGY!don't think I'm actually using this; no INTENT(OUT)
  return [x_temp, v_temp, a_temp, t_temp];
//END
}

//SUBROUTINE FORCE(xs,vs,ts,f_oscs)
function FORCE(i, xs, vs, ts, f_oscs, A_o, const0, gamma) {
  "use strict";
  //USE shared
  //IMPLICIT NONE
  //REAL(dp), INTENT(IN) :: xs,vs,ts
  //REAL(dp), INTENT(OUT) :: f_oscs
  //REAL(dp) :: f_t
  var f_t;
  //f_t = A_o*DCOS(2.0*ts)
  f_t = A_o * Math.cos(2.0 * ts[i]);
  //f_oscs = -const0*xs - gamma*vs + f_t
  f_oscs[i] = -const0 * xs[i] - gamma * vs[i] + f_t;
  return f_oscs;
//END
}

//SUBROUTINE ENERGY()
  //USE shared
  //IMPLICIT NONE
  //!REAL(dp), INTENT(OUT) ::
  //E(i) = 0.5*(v(i)**2 + const0*x(i)**2)
  //E(1) = 0.5*(v(1)**2 + const0*x(1)**2)
  //dE(i) = E(i) - E(1)
//END
```

The original Fortran source is shown in the comments.  Compare the output of position versus time from the original Fortran program:

```
    0.000000        0.100000
    0.010000        0.129930
    0.020000        0.159693
    ...
```

...to that from the translated JavaScript:

```
    0.000000        0.100000
    0.010000        0.129930
    0.020000        0.159707
    ...
```

The results get considerably worse from there.  After 5000 steps the results disagree by a difference of 0.01.  I'm not used to working with arrays in JS, so the error could be in there somewhere.  This is the first time I've encountered something like this.  Does anyone have some insight into what's going on here?

---

#### Update 1

JS by itself:

```
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true */
/*global VERLET */
/*global FORCE */
/*global $ */
function driven() {
  "use strict";
  var i_max,
    i_max_read,
    i,
    x_read,
    v_read,
    const0,
    const0_read,
    gamma,
    gamma_read,
    A_o,
    A_o_read,
    dt,
    dt_read,
    x,
    x_plot,
    v,
    v_plot,
    a,
    a_plot,
    time,
    f_osc,
    sim,
    result,
    nonlinear;
  x = [];
  v = [];
  a = [];
  time = [];
  f_osc = [];//unlike Fortran, this needs to be an array
  time[0] = 0.0;
  i = 0;
  do {
    VERLET(i, x, v, a, time, f_osc, dt, A_o, const0, gamma);
    time[i + 1] = time[i] + dt;
    i = i + 1;
  } while (i < i_max);
}

function VERLET(i, x_temp, v_temp, a_temp, t_temp, f_osc_temp, dt, A_o, const0, gamma) {
  "use strict";
  var m;
  m = 1.0;
  FORCE(i, x_temp, v_temp, t_temp, f_osc_temp, A_o, const0, gamma);
  a_temp[i] = f_osc_temp[i] / m;
  x_temp[i + 1] = x_temp[i] + v_temp[i] * dt + 0.5 * a_temp[i] * dt * dt;
  FORCE(i, x_temp, v_temp, t_temp, f_osc_temp, A_o, const0, gamma);
  a_temp[i + 1] = f_osc_temp[i] / m;
  v_temp[i + 1] = v_temp[i] + 0.5 * (a_temp[i + 1] + a_temp[i]) * dt;
  return [x_temp, v_temp, a_temp, t_temp];
}

function FORCE(i, xs, vs, ts, f_oscs, A_o, const0, gamma) {
  "use strict";
  var f_t;
  f_t = A_o * Math.cos(2.0 * ts[i]);
  f_oscs[i] = -const0 * xs[i] - gamma * vs[i] + f_t;
  return f_oscs;
}
```

---

#### Update 2

This is a similar JS that does *not* exhibit this symptom:

```
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true */
/*global $ */
function amp() {
  "use strict";
  var i_max,
    i,
    m,
    f_osc,
    theta,
    theta_plot,
    omega,
    omega_plot,
    a,
    e,
    e_plot,
    de,
    time,
    theta0,
    read_ratio,
    const0,
    T,
    result,
    omega_read,
    dt_read,
    dt,
    amplitude;
  i_max = 500;
  m = 1.0;
  f_osc = 0.0;
  theta = [];
  omega = [];
  a = [];
  e = [];
  de = [];
  time = [];
  e[0] = 0.5 * (Math.pow(omega[0], 2) + const0 * Math.pow(theta[0], 2));
  time[0] = 0.0;
  i = 0;
  do {
    f_osc = -const0 * Math.sin(theta[i]);
    a[i] = f_osc / m;
    e[i] = 0.5 * (Math.pow(omega[i], 2) + const0 * Math.pow(theta[i], 2));
    de[i] = e[i] - e[0];
    theta[i + 1] = theta[i] + omega[i] * dt + 0.5 * a[i] * dt * dt;
    f_osc = -const0 * Math.sin(theta[i + 1]);
    a[i + 1] = f_osc / m;
    omega[i + 1] = omega[i] + 0.5 * (a[i + 1] + a[i]) * dt;
    e[i] = 0.5 * (Math.pow(omega[i + 1], 2) + const0 * Math.pow(theta[i + 1], 2));
    de[i] = e[i] - e[0];
    time[i + 1] = time[i] + dt;
    i = i + 1;
  } while (i < i_max);
}
```

The big difference being that this one does not contain functions that I'm treating like subroutines.  Am I doing something illegal in that regard?

Comment: I believe you're running into the floating point accuracy problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). I would suggest using a library designed to correct this problem such as the BigDecimal port (https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js).

Comment: What's the datatype of the Fortran numbers? Javascript uses double precision floating point numbers (doubles) with 11 bit exponent and 52 bit mantissa. Doubles are generally considered good enough for physics simulation.

Comment: I have seen many things in my life, but you are the first one to call a Fortran 2008 code "old Fortran program".

Comment: I think I'd rather see the codes separate, its hard to follow either the way you have it.  (Preferably strip out irrelevant stuff related to plotting etc., )

Comment: You've got a difference, between the codes, of `2` in the 5th significant figure at time `0.02`.  I wouldn't dismiss that as just a consequence of the nature of floating-point arithmetic, it looks more like an error to me.  I see you write, in the Javascript `use strict`.  I guess that means stick strictly to IEEE754 floating-point arithmetic ?  If so, did you compile your Fortran with the same strictness ?  Most Fortran compilers don't do that by default 'cos it slows things down.

Comment: Okay, assume it's not an f-p problem.  What could it be?  After all the iterations, I get `0.127338` (Fortran) versus `0.144943` (JS) for the last data point.  That's horrible agreement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second call to FORCE() is doing a different thing than the FORTRAN counterpart...

In FORTRAN, you do something like this:

```
a(i) = FORCE( x(i) , v(i) , time(i) ) / m
a(i+1) = FORCE( x(i) + v(i)*dt + 0.5*a(i)*dt*dt , v(i) , time(i+1) ) / m
```

In JS, you do another thing:

```
a(i) = FORCE( x(i) , v(i) , time(i) ) / m
a(i+1) = FORCE( x(i) , v(i) , time(i) ) / m
```

You're having a real hard time with handling of indices since an intermediate result of FORTRAN a(i+1) will require to mix x(i+1) and v(i)...
So just passing i as parameter does not sound like a good fit
You could set v[i+1]=v[i] and attempt a FORCE(i+1,...) but that sounds too tricky.

Either stick to a closer translation, or attempt a full rewrite.

Comment: The big problem turned out to be that I'm just not that comfortable working with functions/subroutines in JS.  Sticking with a very literal translation and moving `time[i + 1] = time[i] + dt;` to before `t_temp = time[i + 1];` (a newly-found logic problem), the issue is resolved.  Thanks for your help!